# punishment for instigating a crime, intentionally

Tags: halacha, sin, reward-punishment

Is someone who causes another person to sin liable for that sin as if he did it himself?

(Please also consider someone scheming, who intentionally plays stupid people,  causing them to kill each other.)

Do you know Talmud and Torah citations?

Comment: I think so, but no source.

Comment: You should specify liable in bais din (probably not because of ain shliach lidvar aveirah, or min hashmayim (probably yes because of lifnei iver) I do not have exact quotes so I am leaving it a comment. This is based on logic.

Comment: The Rishonim talk about it IIRC -  דברי הרב ודברי תלמיד דברי מי שומעים - does not apply when the תלמיד is under the troublemaker's complete control. Can't find a source easily..

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e217.htm#7

Comment: there is a rambam that discusses one who sics a dog on a person and the person is killed by the dog, what this is considered in halacha. it is not treated as directly killing, cant remember the details or where it is, there is more discussion there of causing death by "playing things". hope someone reading this can fill in.

Comment: One of the "al chet's" in the Yom Kippur service refers (in English translation) to "entrapping a friend." Perhaps this has something to do with instigating a crime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard many times that one who can prevent another from sinning but does not do so, is held responsible for the sin. Kal v'chomer someone who intentionally causes a sin.

However, in such a case, the person bears no fiscal liability.

Yishai brought a parallel case from Hilchos Eidus 17:7. There it states "השוכר עדי שקר להעיד לחברו--פטור מדיני אדם, וחייב בדיני שמיים" - "One who hires false witnesses is free from punishment in human courts but liable in the Heavenly court."

Similar rules will apply to similar cases.